# Theme and Override Privatemsg messages/view/%thread

Tags: 7, views, theming, panels, privatemsg

I've managed to embed all the other pages within Panels as per the D7 Panels/Privatemsg patch, and the only remaining page is the /messages/view/%thread pages. After scouring the Privatemsg API documentation and the internet, I still cannot figure out how to manually present this view or how to embed it in another location either with the API or with regular Drupal theme .tpl.php overrides.

I need to get a sidebar on the /messages/view/* pages, preferably using panels.

1. Is there a function call to produce or print the entire thread list/reply form?
2. Do I have to break the reply form apart from the thread list?
3. After obtaining the thread list using `privatemsg_thread_load()`, is it possible to pass the data back into the overridden privatemsg-view.tpl.php file?

Any and all thoughts or hints are welcome... thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [privatemsg-view.tpl.php](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg-view.tpl.php/7-1).

There is a preprocess hook where you may add theming variables to the privatemsg-view.tpl.php and execute any PHP code there. In my case it was:

```
<?
function MYTHEME_preprocess_privatemsg_view(&$vars) {
  $vars['author_uid'] = $vars['message']->author->uid;
  $vars['realname']= MYMODULE_get_realname($vars['message']->author);
}
?>
```

So here are some alternatives to populate the sidebar:

- Use this PHP code to [trigger a drupal context](http://snipplr.com/view/58723/) which will show a block on the sidebar
- Programtically create other vars like the ones above. Those vars may contain sidebar data  you can use when theming the TPL file which contains the sidebar.

Also, here is a [full privatemsg theming guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26859/how-can-i-customize-the-display-of-messages-sent-with-privatemsg).

Comment: I find it somewhat entertaining that you link to a question in which I have provided the answer :). I was hoping to get the sidebar outside of the `privatemsg-view.tpl.php` template.

Comment: It's possible to print the message list as a PHP block and then drag it to a panel or otherwise put it on the sidebar. See the code in my question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91509/putting-sent-private-messages-into-a-block/94021. Hope this helps.

Comment: @npc, I've edited my answer to include ideas on how to populate the sidebar.